# Thread synchronization printing strings

Tags: c#, multithreading, synchronization

I wrote a small programm which prints "x", then  "+", then again "x" and so on.
The idea was to make it run in two threads so that the first thread prints "x" and the second prints "+". The output looks like this:
"x" -> Thread number 1
"+" -> Thread number 2
"x" -> Thread number 1`enter code here`
"+" -> Thread number 2
and so on..

What I wrote seems to work fine but it seems to me it is written in
very old-fashioned way:

```
 public class Example
 {
    private static int count = 10;
    private static int i = 0;
    private static bool isOneActive = false;


  private static void Run1(object o)
  {
      string s = o as string;

      while(true)
      {
          if (!isOneActive)
          {
              Console.WriteLine("Hello from thread number: " +   
                      Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + " -> " + s);
              isOneActive = true;
              if (i++ > count) break;
          }
      }
  }

  private static void Run2(object o)
  {
      string s = o as string;

      while(true)
      {
          if (isOneActive)
          {
              Console.WriteLine("Hello from thread number: " + 
                Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + " -> " + s);
              isOneActive = false;
              if (i++ > count) break;
          }
      }
  }

  static void Main()
  {
      Thread t1 = new Thread(Run1);
      Thread t2 = new Thread(Run2);
      t1.Start("x");
      t2.Start("+");
  }
```

I know that now .NET has a lot of instruments for thread synchronization as for example ManualResetEvent class and Task library. So how could we write the same programm using ManualResetEvent class? Is it possible at all?

Comment: Partially off-topic, but why do you need to use threads at all when you are writing to the exact same console?

Comment: @Sayse Hi, it was interview question and they said I wrote it in a very old way

Comment: You could use `lock` (or `Monitor.TryEnter`, depends on requirements) to synchronize. You must read [more](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx).

Comment: @Sinatr Yeah, but if I am not mistaking `lock` is used for "locking" the critical sections, not for thread synchronizing/scheduling?

Comment: `lock` works with `Monitor.Pulse` and `Monitor.Wait` but indeed a Waithandle is better here.

Comment: @HenkHolterman That's what they said. I read documentaion but still can't figure out how it works - WaitHandle says to a thread to wait untill the next one releases it?

Comment: With regard to  Sayse's comment: It is a weird requirement to have two threads running one after the other. Why even have two threads in this case? As for your solution, I think the real problem is the inefficient busy-wait.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code isn't only old fashioned, it is very inefficient. It spins for no reason doing nothing but waiting; this is called [Busy wait](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting) should be avoided whenever possible.

Better approach is to use Waithandles as noted in comments.

A naive implementation with very little change in your code will look something like the following.

```
public class Example
{
    private static int count = 10;
    private static int i = 0;
    private static AutoResetEvent firstEvent = new AutoResetEvent(true);
    private static AutoResetEvent secondEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);


    private static void Run1(object o)
    {
        string s = o as string;

        while (true)
        {
            firstEvent.WaitOne();
            Console.WriteLine("Hello from thread number: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + " -> " + s);
            secondEvent.Set();
            if (Interlocked.Increment(ref i) > count)
                break;
        }
    }

    private static void Run2(object o)
    {
        string s = o as string;

        while (true)
        {
            secondEvent.WaitOne();
            Console.WriteLine("Hello from thread number: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + " -> " + s);
            firstEvent.Set();
            if (Interlocked.Increment(ref i) > count)
                break;
        }
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        Thread t1 = new Thread(Run1);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(Run2);
        t1.Start("x");
        t2.Start("+");
    }
}
```

Note that `firstEvent` is instantiated with the initialState flag set to `true` which means that first thread doesn't waits initially.

Comment: Yes, that is just great, exactly that I wanted. But there is one thing I still do not get - `firstEvent` is instantiated with true but in `Run1` `WaitOne` is called. Does not it block the thread1?

Comment: @user3603343 No, when signal is `Set` (we do it by passing true to constructor) calling `WaitOne` will not block. I recommend reading [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27366/Beginner-s-Guide-to-Threading-in-NET-Part-of-n) and [this](http://www.albahari.com/threading/) for good understanding of threading concepts.

Answer (score 3):

Consider this example ([fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/C2FfM5)):

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var console = new object();
        int i = 0;
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            lock (console)
                while (i++ < 10)
                {
                    Console.Write(i);
                    Monitor.Pulse(console);
                    Monitor.Wait(console);
                }
        });
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            lock (console)
                while (i < 10)
                {
                    Console.Write('+');
                    Monitor.Pulse(console);
                    Monitor.Wait(console);
                }
        });
        Console.ReadLine(); // Task.WaitAll might be better, remove for fiddle
    }
```